# 3D Object Detection & Tracking using PCL

Tags: computer-vision, ros, point-cloud-library, object-detection

I have a task where i am asked to **track parcels(carton boxes) of different dimensions moving on a conveyor**

I am using Asus Xtion pro camera and also i have been asked to use Point cloud data to detect & track the object on the conveyor

I have read so many model-based methods where we need to create a model of the object to be detected and then we perform keypoints extraction,feature mapping and so many other concepts between the scene and the model. 
Since i am using Boxes of different dimensions, i definitely need a model of each of them to match with the scene.

My question : Can i have one common point cloud model of a box of some dimension and compare it with any box that comes under the view of a camera? I meant can i have one scalable model to compare with box of any dimension? is it possible?

My chief doesn't want the project to be dependent on many models for detection and tracking. One common model which is scalable or parameterized should do the trick it seems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the color of your boxes are distinct, maybe basic color based segmentation would work.

Comment: I am using Point cloud for detecting and tracking objects. Can colour based segmentation suit my task??

Comment: Why not? You have the RGBD image, right? It's the simplest method and if the color is enough to segment the foreground, there is no need to go with complicated methods.

Comment: Yea okie..Thank u so much.. i Will try and get back to this thread :)